# how to handle network during live video with tokbox?

Tags: android, live-streaming, tokbox

I am using tokbox sdk for go live but i am not able to handle network for subscriber during live when publisher internet is off there is no any call back to notify to subscriber after 10 to 20 second connection is terminate and sesion disconnect but if any way to notify geting call back to show message to subscriber.

Comment: Which TokBox SDK are you using? iOS? Android? Web?

Comment: i am using Android SDK

Comment: Yeah, the same answer below applies. But instead you listen for onStreamDropped
https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/subscribe-stream/android/#detect_streams_leave_session

Answer (score 0):

When a publisher loses it's internet connection a streamDestroyed event should be dispatched to all of the other participants with a reason code of 'networkDisconnected'. More details at:

https://tokbox.com/developer/guides/subscribe-stream/js/#detect_streams_leave_session